# Allegro library installation

Tags: allegro

I was using Dev C++ Compiler and due to some problems this compiler is not running properly on my PC,and for that i am unable to install Allegro 4.9 Library with my Dev C++ compiler.
I am now using netbeans compiler for my c++ programming but unable to install Allegro library on that compiler.

I can't use MSVS because it took alot of memory space.

I admire if you can suggest me any compiler on which i can install Allegro Library,or the procedure to install Allegro on my netbeans compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Code::Blocks and using pre-built binaries (MinGW) for Allegro 5.0 available at http://www.allegro.cc/files. The documentation and http://wiki.allegro.cc show you how to install and use Allegro.